# how to see background image through contour outline

Tags: graphics, contour, transparent

I am trying to make a book cover with the title a contour outline over an image, where you can see the image through the letters.  Essentially, I would like the color of the fill (textcolor) to be "none."

The following is approaching what I want, but the words would have to be placed precisely over the same image so that it lines up, and would need an outline.
[Background clip to text Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249717/background-clip-to-text-tikz)

There's also this, but I can't figure out how to apply it.
[Tikz with contour and transparency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140437/tikz-with-contour-and-transparency)

Here's a MWE, but obviously I can't see the image through the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
    \textsf{\textbf{\Huge\contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{TITLE}}}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Ti*k*Z is not the best tool for this. You want something where you can turn the text into a path, basically. Metapost, possibly. Inkscape, definitely. That's not to say you can't do it with Ti*k*Z, but it doesn't lend itself to this kind of job.

Comment: Thanks @cfr for the idea.  I created a PDF with the color fill, then deleted the fill in Photoshop and exported it to SVG, which I then included.